# How to mix the order of items of a Django object on a page?

Tags: python, django, random

I am trying to create a game that allows users to play a quiz, which is stored as a Django object, but I want the order of the questions to be different (as in random) every time. Is there a way to accomplish this?

models.py

```
class Quiz(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="")
    title = models.TextField(default="")
    question1 = models.TextField()
    answer1 = models.TextField()
    question2 = models.TextField()
    answer2 = models.TextField(default="")
    question3 = models.TextField()
    answer3 = models.TextField()
    ...
```

(The questions and answers go to 10.)

views.py

```
def quiz(request, quiz_id):
    quiz = get_object_or_404(Quiz.objects, pk=quiz_id)
    return render(request, "capstone/quiz.html", {
        "quiz": quiz
        })
```

I was thinking about generating a random number, but I think that would be too complicated with the number of questions. Is there any easier way to randomly display the questions to the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below will extract the questions from your queryset into a tuple containing the question and the question number, and then shuffle the tuples, putting them into their own context value

```
import random
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict

def quiz(request, quiz_id):
    quiz = get_object_or_404(Quiz.objects, pk=quiz_id)
    #convert the queryset into a dict so we can get the questions
    quiz_values = model_to_dict(quiz)
    quiz_questions = []
    for i in range(1,11):
        quiz_questions.append((i, quiz_values['question' + str(i)]))
    random.shuffle(quiz_questions)
    return render(request, "capstone/quiz.html", {
        "quiz": quiz, "quiz_questions": quiz_questions
        })
```

Then in your template, you can refer to  something like

```
{% for q in quiz_questions %}
   {{q.1}} <!-- question text  -->
   <input type="text" name="id_question{{q.0}}">  <!-- question number -->
{% endfor %}
```

...so your form doesn't lose track of which question is being answered.

Comment: As an aside, you may find it easier to split quiz, quiz questions and answers, and user answers into separate but related models.  Then you can simply do a query for all the questions related to the quiz and use order_by('?') to randomise them. That would require some database restructuring, though.

Comment: I am getting this error: ```'Quiz' object has no attribute 'values'```.

Comment: D'oh.  Sorry, that would work for objects.filter, but not objects.get.  Instead you can import and use the model_to_dict function. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: that worked. How am I supposed to display the text of the question? In your answer you have written a comment for the question text. I thought ```{{ q.1 }}``` would get the question text, but nothing shows up.

Comment: It should.  Have a look at {{ quiz_questions }} in your template and see what's inside.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use a embedded [ORM function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by).

```
Quiz.objects.order_by('?')
```